# Is there a arm64 build

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, arm64

I am using a raspberry pi and I am trying to do a project where I want to turn my Raspberry pi 4 into a development machine to write spring boot applications for API development so far it has been a success. But to test the API I use curl. I need a GUI client So I came across Advanced rest client. if there is an arm build that will be awesome. Or if I have to build from scratch I can do that on my raspberry pi. But I need to know the build process. If anyone can point to to any documentation or readme that will be great.

I think the source is at :

https://github.com/advanced-rest-client/arc-electron

Comment: The source code is available, you just have to compile it

Comment: You should provide a link to the source code in your question . If you don't, you are putting the burden of finding it on people you want to get help from.